# Error NPM run dev

Tags: laravel, npm, auth

Luego de instalar laravel 7.*, ejecuto para la autenticación

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Cuando termina de ejecutar sugiere el siguiente codigo

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error

```
> @ development /var/www/laravel/proyecto7
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/var/www/laravel/proyecto7/node_modules/cross-env/src/index.js:23
    )
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/laravel/proyecto7/node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js:3:18)
```

Este es el SO donde lo tengo instalado

```
    Virtualization: vmware
  Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.7
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:7:server
            Kernel: Linux 4.14.35-1902.10.7.el7uek.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis, podrías agregar el fragmento de código donde se genera?

Comment: lo que parece un error de sintaxis, es el error que me aparece, pero ese es un archivo que se genera solo o hace parte de los paquetes que preinstala, no es un archivo que yo edito

Comment: Prueba actualizando node https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730815/cross-env-dist-index-js42-unexpected-token/48171302#48171302

Comment: Muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ, tu comentario me solucionó el problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solución:
Al parecer es un problema con las versiones de NPM que se instala.  Lo mejor es hacer una reinstalación a una versión estable.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Posterior a ello se refresca

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm run dev
```

Todo lo ejecuté desde la carpeta del proyecto.

Respuesta original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730815/cross-env-dist-index-js42-unexpected-token/48171302#48171302

Comment: Gracias!! en la respuesta original es necesario tambien ejecutar `wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xJf node-v6.9.2-linux-x64.tar.xz` cuando hay problemas con node luego `npm install`